# HTML to XML Conversion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

http://jsbin.com/rigokaquce/1/edit

How should I modify the code to get the choice selected by radio button in the HTML in the final  XML output generated. I have tried to do it with the help of ID's but in spite of the selection performed I get whole data in the final XML output

Comment: slightly off-topic question: why? HTML is for browsers, XML is for data parsers. Converting to XML for rendering in the browser is the opposite of a good idea.

Comment: This is a small part of a website development in which i need to get a copy of the selected data in the HTML page to a XML file. So I have certain limitations with regard to that.

Comment: where are you doing this, then? client side or server side? Because users generally can't select HTML, they select Ranges, which you can then POST to your server for proper processing.

Comment: I am doing this on the client side. By selection I mean the selecting the options available on the HTML page

Comment: the HTML in your fiddle's fairly insane (you're using a deprecated form of HTML from 1998, rather than modern HTML) but you'd simply check which of the inputs in your radio button group "radio1" is marked as `checked` (make sure not to pre-check an option): wrap your inputs in a `<form>` and you can grab your entire group as a NodeList using document.forms[0].radio1